# GNU Octave draw figure of 2 planes

Tags: surfaces, plane-curves, octave

How can I draw two planes in same figure in GNU Octave?

$$ x + y + z = 1\\
    2x - y + 3z = 4$$

Thanks!

Comment: Does Octave use the `hold` command like Matlab does?

Comment: Yes there is function hold

Comment: Can you use this function to get what you want? That is, draw the first plane, hold the figure, and then draw the second one.

Comment: Thanks I got it :) How can I vote up for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AnonSubmitter85 says in comments, use `hold` between the plot commands to plot in the same figure.